# Cann't write java 8 code at eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, java-8

I installed java 8 on Lubuntu 13.10. It is pre release but it should work - [JDK™ 8 Early Access Releases](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html).

I added **JDk** to eclipse:

[image]

And tried wrote first java 8 version code.

This code should find the longest word.

I caught a bunch of exceptions:

for `12` line - it shows:

> Multiple markers at this line
>     - Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 1.5 or 
>      greater
>     - Resource specification not allowed here for source level below 1.7

[image]

Why does this exactly happen?

**How to solve this trouble?**

Comment: Just to double check, is stuff like `System.out::println` Java 8 syntax?

Comment: Doesn't Eclipse use it's own internal version of the compiler?

Comment: At the very least you need to go into Project Properties -> Java Compiler -> Compiler Compliance Level and set it to 1.7.  Based on your errors you have it set to 1.4 or lower.  This will allow you to at least get rid of the errors related to syntax that requires Java 7.  Java 8 syntax isn't supported by eclipse yet, but it should still allow you to compile and run code.

Comment: @DennisMeng you must be kidding, it is one of main feature.

Comment: @nazar_art Just checking. Guess I'm still stuck in my Java 7 ways. :P

Comment: @Jherico Do you know will java 8 supported at kepler (or at next version)?

Comment: @nazar_art It may be supported by an update of the JDT.  There's already an early release version available that looks like it can be installed in Kepler.  See https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core/Java8

Comment: @Jherico can you explain at more detail how to set up this one at eclipse kepler. you able to write answer for clarify.

Comment: I just found the web page.  I can't explain it to you any better than that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse JDT environment -- editors and tools -- only supports Java Syntax up to 1.7.  As of today, Java 1.8 support is only available in early access releases.

Adding a JDK or JRE to Eclipse does no change the characteristics of the JDT environment, which is a highly-integrated set of tools.  So, until Eclipse releases Java 1.8 support and that makes its way into your distribution, you will not be able to use the Java editor for any syntax that is unique to Java 1.8.

Comment: You can work with the Beta Java 1.8 support by installing Eclipse 4.3.1 and the add-on according to the instructions here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_(BETA).  AFAIK, IntelliJ 13.x does have 1.8 support.  Please accept answer if OK.

Comment: I run this code on Intellij 13, Output is - `electroencephalograph's`